# Java user control region

Tags: java, custom-controls, region

I'm new to Java, and i'd like to know if Java has something similar to the C# region which defines which parts of the control's area should react to mouse event, etc.
(like in creating a round button...)
thanks :)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778222/make-a-button-round

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The method `contains(int, int)` in the `java.awt.Component` class is used to query a control to ask whether it contains a particular point, for the purposes of mouse processing. If you're defining a custom control, you can override this method to describe the shape.