# Button with round edges

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, button, jbutton

I am trying to get a button with round edges. My button has a background color of yellow. I am not able to get the round edge for my button. Here is the code i am trying

```
 class RoundedBorder implements Border {
        int radius;
        RoundedBorder(int radius) {
            this.radius = radius;
        }
        public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c) {
            return new Insets(this.radius+1, this.radius+1, this.radius+2, this.radius);
        }
        public boolean isBorderOpaque() {
            return true;
        }
        public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
            g.drawRoundRect(x,y,width-1,height-1,radius,radius);
        }
    }

jButton1.setText(aContinue);
        jButton1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 0));
        jButton1.setBorder(new RoundedBorder(20));
```

I am not able to get round edges using this piece of code.. Here is how my button looks .

[image]

I want to have round edges with no overflowing background color.

Comment: Don't let Steve Jobs see this question.... He invented rounded edges!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found this great example by oracle which supplies a class which creates [RoundButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/awt/demos/lightweight/RoundButtons/actual/RoundButton.java).

[image]

Here is an example using an edited `RoundButton` class to create `RoundedButton` class:

[image]

```
import java.awt.AWTEvent;
import java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class Test {

    public Test() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final JTextField tf = new JTextField("");

        RoundedButton rb = new RoundedButton("Go");
        rb.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        rb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "You said: " + tf.getText());
            }
        });

        frame.add(tf, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(rb);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test();
            }
        });
    }
}

class RoundedButton extends Component {

    ActionListener actionListener;     // Post action events to listeners
    String label;                      // The Button's text
    protected boolean pressed = false; // true if the button is detented.

    /**
     * Constructs a RoundedButton with no label.
     */
    public RoundedButton() {
        this("");
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a RoundedButton with the specified label.
     *
     * @param label the label of the button
     */
    public RoundedButton(String label) {
        this.label = label;
        enableEvents(AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK);
    }

    /**
     * gets the label
     *
     * @see setLabel
     */
    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    /**
     * sets the label
     *
     * @see getLabel
     */
    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
        invalidate();
        repaint();
    }

    /**
     * paints the RoundedButton
     */
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        // paint the interior of the button
        if (pressed) {
            g.setColor(getBackground().darker().darker());
        } else {
            g.setColor(getBackground());
        }
        g.fillRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1, 20, 20);

        // draw the perimeter of the button
        g.setColor(getBackground().darker().darker().darker());
        g.drawRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1, 20, 20);

        // draw the label centered in the button
        Font f = getFont();
        if (f != null) {
            FontMetrics fm = getFontMetrics(getFont());
            g.setColor(getForeground());
            g.drawString(label, getWidth() / 2 - fm.stringWidth(label) / 2, getHeight() / 2 + fm.getMaxDescent());
        }
    }

    /**
     * The preferred size of the button.
     */
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        Font f = getFont();
        if (f != null) {
            FontMetrics fm = getFontMetrics(getFont());
            int max = Math.max(fm.stringWidth(label) + 40, fm.getHeight() + 40);
            return new Dimension(max, max);
        } else {
            return new Dimension(100, 100);
        }
    }

    /**
     * The minimum size of the button.
     */
    @Override
    public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
        return new Dimension(100, 100);
    }

    /**
     * Adds the specified action listener to receive action events from this
     * button.
     *
     * @param listener the action listener
     */
    public void addActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
        actionListener = AWTEventMulticaster.add(actionListener, listener);
        enableEvents(AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK);
    }

    /**
     * Removes the specified action listener so it no longer receives action
     * events from this button.
     *
     * @param listener the action listener
     */
    public void removeActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
        actionListener = AWTEventMulticaster.remove(actionListener, listener);
    }

    /**
     * Determine if click was inside round button.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean contains(int x, int y) {
        int mx = getSize().width / 2;
        int my = getSize().height / 2;
        return (((mx - x) * (mx - x) + (my - y) * (my - y)) <= mx * mx);
    }

    /**
     * Paints the button and distribute an action event to all listeners.
     */
    @Override
    public void processMouseEvent(MouseEvent e) {
        Graphics g;
        switch (e.getID()) {
            case MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED:
                // render myself inverted....
                pressed = true;

                // Repaint might flicker a bit. To avoid this, you can use
                // double buffering (see the Gauge example).
                repaint();
                break;
            case MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED:
                if (actionListener != null) {
                    actionListener.actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(
                            this, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, label));
                }
                // render myself normal again
                if (pressed == true) {
                    pressed = false;

                    // Repaint might flicker a bit. To avoid this, you can use
                    // double buffering (see the Gauge example).
                    repaint();
                }
                break;
            case MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED:

                break;
            case MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED:
                if (pressed == true) {
                    // Cancel! Don't send action event.
                    pressed = false;

                    // Repaint might flicker a bit. To avoid this, you can use
                    // double buffering (see the Gauge example).
                    repaint();

                    // Note: for a more complete button implementation,
                    // you wouldn't want to cancel at this point, but
                    // rather detect when the mouse re-entered, and
                    // re-highlight the button. There are a few state
                    // issues that that you need to handle, which we leave
                    // this an an excercise for the reader (I always
                    // wanted to say that!)
                }
                break;
        }
        super.processMouseEvent(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome help..thanks..can this code tweaked for jtextfield ??

Comment: @Ragssure it can but it will really actually be an entirely new class which extedns Component class rather than tweaking the original as JTextField is very different from a JButton

Comment: @Rags my mistake it might be even easier if you extend [`JTextComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html)

Comment: As of july 2018, i´m getting black corners around the rounded buttons. Only on windows (same button on linux works ok)

Comment: Link to oracle is broken

Answer (score 5):

**Option1**- Use Images

**Option2**- Use the following code (Extracted from [Make a button round](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778222/make-a-button-round))

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class RoundButton extends JButton {
  public RoundButton(String label) {
    super(label);

// These statements enlarge the button so that it 
// becomes a circle rather than an oval.
    Dimension size = getPreferredSize();
    size.width = size.height = Math.max(size.width, 
      size.height);
    setPreferredSize(size);

// This call causes the JButton not to paint 
   // the background.
// This allows us to paint a round background.
    setContentAreaFilled(false);
  }

// Paint the round background and label.
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    if (getModel().isArmed()) {
// You might want to make the highlight color 
   // a property of the RoundButton class.
      g.setColor(Color.lightGray);
    } else {
      g.setColor(getBackground());
    }
    g.fillOval(0, 0, getSize().width-1, 
      getSize().height-1);

// This call will paint the label and the 
   // focus rectangle.
    super.paintComponent(g);
  }

// Paint the border of the button using a simple stroke.
  protected void paintBorder(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(getForeground());
    g.drawOval(0, 0, getSize().width-1, 
      getSize().height-1);
  }

// Hit detection.
  Shape shape;
  public boolean contains(int x, int y) {
// If the button has changed size, 
   // make a new shape object.
    if (shape == null || 
      !shape.getBounds().equals(getBounds())) {
      shape = new Ellipse2D.Float(0, 0, 
        getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
    return shape.contains(x, y);
  }

// Test routine.
  public static void main(String[] args) {
// Create a button with the label "Jackpot".
    JButton button = new RoundButton("Jackpot");
    button.setBackground(Color.green);

// Create a frame in which to show the button.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.yellow);
    frame.getContentPane().add(button);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.setSize(150, 150);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

**Option3**-  Use Look and Feel that supports Round Buttons http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/NimbusLookandFeel_OBE2012/CustomizingLandF.html

**Option4**-  Go with JavaFX and use CSS. There are free CSS scripts supporting this

Answer (score 0):

Another clean way to make this happen is to define a custom `ButtonUI` that would draw a rounded corner button.